# Set a country background to my Google Geomap

Tags: image, replace, background-image, google-visualization, geomap

A few days ago I've explored geomaps and, however, it turned out to be easy to change the properties of the elements.

But I have two questions:

- I'd like to add rivers and forests on the maps. So Ive considered to set a background image instead of the geomaps figure. But I can't find a way to get this one fixed. Is there a way to set a background picture for a country or region?
- How can I change the shape of the "bubbles" when you select a city e.g. "London"? I'd like to change it to a square.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you're looking for is not available in geocharts in their current implementation.

Using a background image is possible in the sense that you can use CSS to make all shapes in the map transparent, and use a background image in the div to make it appear as if the little circles are being drawn on a map with forest and rivers, but you will run in to two big hurdles:

1. Your map will need to be identical in size/layout to the Google Maps SVG
2. If Google ever changes the SVG they use (or the view/projection they use) you will need to edit yours too

This isn't ideal, obviously. You could work around it by creating custom javascript to write rivers and forests on your map, but that is going to be a huge headache (especially if you are using multiple maps/views).

As for the circles, you can't change them to squares without hacking the actual SVG in the background with javascript. While this is definitely possible (if you're really good with SVG/Javascript), it again isn't using any of the fancy features of geocharts, and is more just a custom solution that will have to be updated if/when google updates their API.

Rather than doing it that way, you may want to look in to the same implementation on google maps itself. That will allow you to use custom markers, draw custom shapes, etc. with a lot more flexibility (and a much more stable API).